# Problem with Golang MongoDB Aggregate Queries

Tags: mongodb, go, aggregate-functions, database-cursor

All, I've posted this a second time since I've yet to get any sort of response. For more detailed reference please see the following link:

[Golang MongoDB query returns empty cursor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69916748/golang-mongodb-query-returns-empty-cursor)

Bottom line is that I can't seem to get a valid non-zero cursor returned when dealing with document returns in the 100s. If I query a Mongodb collection through Golang and it returns 10s of documents I have no problem. Is there some type of limit that I am missing?